# Android Websocket Service Persistent Connection

Tags: android, service, websocket, android-webservice

I implemented a chat application in Android with websockets. However when the user closes the application, the websocket connection to the server is lost and no new messages can be received.

I am essentially lost and do not know where else to turn, how can I setup the service in the app to stay connected to the server as the user logs in as well as after the app has been stopped?

Comment: Bump,, have you tried implementing a service? And did it keep the connection up always? I am trying to do the same

Answer (score 4):

As we're all aware, continuous background code execution is not feasible on Android; different ROMs will man-handle your background services without any guarantees (e.g. `START_STICKY` will not get your service restarted on some devices), so we need to do the best we can with the code that *is* reliably executed.

In this situation, you have a websocket server delivering continous information to your client. When your app is in the background, it may miss out on some data. When your app returns to the foreground, your information may be out of sync, so you need to synchronize again with your server, and then reconnect to your websocket.

In my chat app I achieve this by checking whether my websocket service is running `onResume` in an activity which is a superclass of all the activities that I want to have access chatting data (i.e. not login/registration activities). If the service is not running, I synchronize my data by pulling the changes from an endpoint and then restarting the service. This way, even if the service is killed in the background I will still get the latest data and real-time experience once the app returns to the foreground.

Comment: I actually ended up using firebase from Google, why reinvent the wheel...?

Comment: Firebase is great, however its DB is not that flexible and we already had our own so we chose to build our own Firebase :)

Comment: @Sauron why? maybe because it sux? https://medium.com/@scosta/why-firebase-sucks-ce5d2302eb20

Comment: @urgentx, you mentioned when the user reconnects and if the service was not running, you would sync the data and then restart the service. What if new data has been put in the gap between syncing and reconnecting?

Comment: Better to reconnect first then :)