# Handling Websockets - Where should I place my code to handle websocket connection in Android?

Tags: android, websocket, okhttp

I am trying to establish a websocket connection on my server. Where do I place the code to connect, reconnect if connection closed, etc, in my Android app so that if the app is closed the websocket connection will still work?

```
public class EchoWebSocketListener extends WebSocketListener {
        @Override
        public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, okhttp3.Response response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onOpen: Opened: " + response.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onMessage: Recieved: " + text);
           
        }

        @Override
        public void onClosing(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClosing: onClosing");
        }

        @Override
        public void onClosed(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClosed: Closed: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, okhttp3.Response response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: Failure" + t);
            //createNewWebsocketConnection();
        }
    }

    private void createNewWebsocketConnection(){

        if(mUserId != null){
            EchoWebSocketListener listener = new EchoWebSocketListener();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(MAIN_WS_URL)
                    .addHeader("user_id_connection", mUserId)
                    .build();

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient
                    .Builder()
                    .pingInterval(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build();
            ws = client.newWebSocket(request, listener);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You should probably use a Service to handle such tasks

Comment: which type of service is usually recommended for WS? Theres multiple but I don't know which one to choose

Comment: These should help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29090505/android-websocket-services-making-multiple-connections

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29481798/android-websocket-service-persistent-connection

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46780547/websocket-paused-when-android-app-goes-to-background

Comment: Were you able to conclude anything from the above links?